# window function sql - how to get orders by login type with less records of logins than orders

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get a share of orders by the login type, having login types in one table and orders & platforms in another table. I am facing problem because the login records of the user is not always in the same date of the order placed, therefore when join both tables I have null login dates and null login types. A want to find a way to tell big query to get the last login record if the result is null.

currently I am left join login and orders by user ID, country and login date <= order date - which results in duplicates because it creates combinations of of login< order date and login = order date.
I have also tried with MAX login and eft join login and orders by user ID, country and login date <= order date - it delete duplicates if the login type (from login table) is the same. if the login type is different then it applies login< order date and login = order and results in duplicates for those records.

I am not sure if there is a window function that can help me here.

Example:
[tables and current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZXA.png)

**query I am using **

```
WITH login AS (
SELECT login_date,
Country,
Userid ,
loginType
FROM login
WHERE login_date  between '2023-01-01' AND '2023-09-30’
 ),

orders AS (
SELECT order_date,
Country,
Userid ,
Platform,
COUNT(*) as orders
FROM  orders
WHERE order_date between '2023-01-01' AND '2023-09-30’
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
 )

SELECT MAX(login_date) login,
order_date,
l. Userid,
o.Country,
o.Platform,
l.loginType,
o.orders
from orders o
left join login l ON l.Userid = o.Userid AND l.Country = o.Country AND o.order_date >= l.login_date 
group by 2,3,4,5,6,7
order by order_date desc
```

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGc7F.png)

Comment: i think it helps to have data in table format, right now it's really hard to read

Comment: Also, you should remove sql server if you aren't on sql server :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```
with login as (
    select
        login_date,
        lead(login_date, 1, '9999-12-31')
            over (partition by Country, Userid, loginType) as next_login_date,
        Country, Userid, loginType
    from login
    where login_date between '2022-12-01' and '2023-09-30'
 ),
orders as (
    select order_date, Country, Userid, Platform, count(*) as orders
    from orders
    where order_date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-09-30'
    group by 1, 2, 3, 4
 )
select
    l.login_date, l.Userid, o.Country, o.Platform, l.loginType
from orders o left outer join login l
    on l.Userid = o.Userid and l.Country = o.Country
       and o.order_date between l.login_date and l.next_login_date 
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
having count(*) > 1
order by order_date desc;
```

I don't know exactly what you want or if BigQuery has a "better" way. You might find this as usable approach to getting the most recent login date via `lead()` and using `between` in the join condition. You probably also want to add a cushion on the login windows prior to the start of the order range. I'm not sure how big that needs to be.